# Rendering Ajax request in React-Router Children

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, react-router, setstate

I'm having a problem with React-Router and AJAX requests.

Here is the index.js (the entry file):

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { App } from './App';
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory } from 'react-router';

import Utente from './routes/Utente';
import UtenteView from './routes/UtenteView';

render(
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" utente={mattia} component={App}>
      <Route path="user/:id" component={User}>
        <IndexRoute component={UserView}/>
        <Route path="rete" component={Rete}></Route>
      </Route>
    </Route>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

The App.js file has only the render function, that returns

```
<div>{this.props.children}</div>
```

to call the User component. The User file is almost the same.

In the UserView.js file, I make an AJAX request with [superagent](http://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import request from 'superagent';

export default class UserView extends Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      result: null
    };
    this.fetchRequest = this.fetchRequest.bind(this)
  }
  makeRequest(id){
    request
      .get('/API/user/' + id)
      .end(function(err, value){
        if (value){
          return({
            result: JSON.parse(value.text).name
          })
        }
      });
  }

  fetchRequest(){
    this.setState(this.makeRequest(this.props.params.id));
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.fetchRequest();
  }

  render(){
    if(typeof this.state.result !== 'undefined'){
      return(
      <div>
        <p>Questa è la pagina di {oggetto.id}</p>
      </div>
      )
    }
    return(
      <div>
        <h4>Loading data...</h4>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

But this doesn't work and it's giving me the error:

```
Warning: setState(...): You passed an undefined or null state object; instead, use forceUpdate().
```

Why? I think that the error is in the fact that I'm trying to manipulate the state of the parents through the children.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `makeRequest` is asynchronous and you can't `return` from it.  You should do this instead:

```
makeRequest(id){
  request
    .get('/API/user/' + id)
    .end((err, value) => {
      if (value){
        this.setState({
          result: JSON.parse(value.text).name
        })
      }
    });
}
```

Also, I would do something like this with your component.  You should not override the constructor for you setup.  Also, check out fetch:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import fetch from 'whatwg-fetch';

export default class UserView extends Component{

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchRequest(this.props.params.id)
  },

  fetchRequest(){
    fetch('/API/user/' + id)
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json()
      })
      .then((json) => {
        this.setState({
          result: json.name
        })
      })
      .catch((ex) => {
        console.log('parsing failed', ex)
      })
  }

  getLoadingMessage() {
    if(typeof this.state.result === 'undefined') {
      return
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <h4>Loading data...</h4>
      </div>
    )
  },

  getMessage() {
    if(typeof this.state.result !== 'undefined') {
      return
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <p>Questa è la pagina di {oggetto.id}</p>
      </div>
    )
  },

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        { this.getLoadingMessage() }
        { this.getMessage() }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I've already tried this way, but now the error is: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined.

Comment: are you using an arrow function `() => {}` for your .end callback?

Comment: No. With the arrow function it works! Thank you! I was thinking that using `.bind(this)` was enough. Thank you!